# Passing non PODs [ Plain old DataTypes ] over IPC

Tags: c++, c, ipc, message-queue, dbus

I am writing an implementation for doing IPC. User do a call, I take all these parameters and pass them onto other process.

I have written an automatic code generator for such functions based on logic which works something like this :

1. Take all the parameters and put them inside a structure.
2. Add other information required for IPC. Pass the size and pointer of this struct to POSIX message queue. **Data from this address, till the size specified, is read and send to other process.**
3. De-construct the struct to get parameters.
4. Call the actual function with these parameters.

This works perfectly fine when I have only Plain old Data types. But when the function parameters are non-PODs, my logic fails because :

1. I cant really tell the size of total data in case of non-POD type [Required by message queues]
2. Some classes might contain dynamically increasing entities like vectors.

Can someone give an idea how I might approach for this situation?

Comment: Read about [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). Also see e.g. [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

Comment: I wrote this. https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer It serializes C++ objects as Json (and deserializes them). Not as good as the Google stuff but very simple to use.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I read about Boost Serialization. From what I understood, data is serialized into a file and then de serialized. But this data is written on Hard Disk! wouldn't that be too much of an over head in terms of speed, to access Hard Disk for transferring data, for an IPC mechanism ?

Comment: The existing archive classes in Boost Serialization support any stream, and so can be used for any C++ iostream (for example [Boost ASIO `ip::tcp::iostream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/iostream.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide how to do serialization.

E.g. you could define a type which represents a message which is exchanged between parties, and then implement a generic function which serializes objects into message. When you have custom logic, you specialize the serialization function.

here's some pseudocode:

```
class Message {...} // blah blah

// default imple
template<typename T>
Message& operator <<(Message& msg, T& t) { .. write it as a POD .. }

// specialize for types which need custom logic
Message& operator <<(Message& msg, SomeCustomType& x) { .. custom serialization ..}
```

To deserialize you need to do similar for `operator >>`. Then you do:

```
Message msg;
MyType whatever = ...
msg << whatever;
// now send msg to other side.
```

Of course you will need some metadata in message so you know how to unpack on the other side (i.e. to which type).

There are plenty of examples (e.g. STL streams or how MFC abstracts it with CArchive class and `Serialize` method on serializable types)